# Azure Cosmos: Register Stored Procedure If not exist already

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I want to register and execute stored proc. I am using spring+Java with cosmos DB. Everytime I stop my application and restart it , it tried to create new sproc and since it already exists in cosmos DB it fails with below error . Is their any option available like "only create if not exist". I am fetching js file from src/main/resources folder.

I am following below doc to register the stored proc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=java-sdk

```
@Configuration
public class StoredProcConfig
{
@Autowired
@Qualifier(BeansConstants.PAYMENT_CONTAINER)
CosmosContainer container;

@Bean
public CosmosStoredProcedureResponse registerSp() throws IOException
{
    InputStream is = getFileFromResourceAsStream("storedProcedures/createStudent.js");
    CosmosStoredProcedureProperties definition = new CosmosStoredProcedureProperties("spCreateToDoItems",
            IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    return container.getScripts().createStoredProcedure(definition);
}


private InputStream getFileFromResourceAsStream(String fileName)
{

    // The class loader that loaded the class
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);

    // the stream holding the file content
    if (inputStream == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("file not found! " + fileName);
    } else
    {
        return inputStream;
    }
}
```

}

Error

```
Caused by: com.azure.cosmos.CosmosException: {"innerErrorMessage":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Resource with specified id, name, or unique index already exists.\"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your registerSp() bean as below:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CosmosConfiguration.class);

@Bean
public CosmosStoredProcedureResponse registerSp() throws IOException
{
    InputStream is = getFileFromResourceAsStream("storedProcedures/createStudent.js");
    CosmosStoredProcedureProperties definition = new CosmosStoredProcedureProperties("spCreateToDoItems",
            IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return createStoredProcedureIfNotExists(definition);
}

public CosmosStoredProcedureResponse createStoredProcedureIfNotExists(CosmosStoredProcedureProperties definition){
    try {
        CosmosStoredProcedureResponse storedProc = container.getScripts().getStoredProcedure(definition.getId()).read();
        logger.info("found stored proc");
        return storedProc;
    }
    catch (CosmosException e){
        logger.info("stored proc not found, creating....");
        return container.getScripts().createStoredProcedure(definition);
    }
}
```